# Bundle install broken on ruby 2.0 upgrade

Tags: ruby, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Just upgraded to ruby 2.0/rails 4.0 and trying to run bundle install on a new rails project. Whenever it hits something that's not already installed, it'll spit out:

```
Installing coffee-rails (4.0.0.beta1) 
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/build_info/coffee-rails-4.0.0.beta1.info
An error occurred while installing coffee-rails (4.0.0.beta1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install coffee-rails -v '4.0.0.beta1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So then I then run

```
gem install coffee-rails -v '4.0.0.beta1'
```

And it installs fine, and I rerun bundle install and have to repeat this for every time it runs into a gem version I haven't installed yet. What's the problem here?

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like.

Comment: Whatever the default gemfile is for new rails projects?

Comment: What version of bundler?

Comment: What's your OS? What tools did you use to install ruby?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 8):

In my case it turned out that bundle was trying to install gems into global location at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0, but since I didn't invoke it through sudo it ended up with permission error. I wanted to install to my home dir anyhow so it turned out that I can do:

```
GEM_HOME=~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/ bundle
```

and live happily ever after.

Answer (score 4):

The `bundle` executable is just a shell script, and it has a shebang line which will be pointing to a particular Ruby executable (or to `/usr/bin/env ruby`).  It sounds like that shebang line is pointing to a different version of Ruby, not the 2.0 one, and not the one that the shebang line in your `gem` executable is pointing to.

Run this to see what it's pointing to: `head -1 $(which bundle)`

Whatever line that shows you, strip off the `#!` prefix and run that line with the `-v` switch to see which version of Ruby it is (if it's not obvious).  So if the shebang line was `#!/usr/bin/ruby` then run `/usr/bin/ruby -v`  If my theory is correct then you'll get a non 2.0 version number there.

Based on what you said, your `gem` executable is pointing to the 2.0 Ruby, so the fix here is to just uninstall and then reinstalled the bundler gem.  That *should* put the right Ruby 2.0 shebang line into your `bundle` executable.

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me:

`sudo gem update --system --no-user-install`

source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=138650

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Gemfile and then run bundle install.

```
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', github: 'rails/coffee-rails'
end
```

Comment: this gem was just an example, it happens with ANY gem that I don't have installed.

Comment: In Rails 4 there is no assets group anymore.